# Top 500 Companies in the World – Data

Tags: data, market-data

At the basis of an algorithm, I need an Excel/CSV file containing the world's top 500 companies (with respect to market cap, preferably free-float if possible) by Name, Country, Market-Cap (in USD, or weight points, just something consistent).
Do you know where I can get this data for free?

I was able to find relevant resources [here](https://www.ftserussell.com/analytics/factsheets/home/constituentsweights) and [here](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener).
The problem with the first resource is mostly the format, I tried to use tabula (python library) in order to convert the pdf into a table, but the results were not satisfying.
The problem with the second is that it only contains companies listed as ADRs in the US.

Comment: Not really, what you requested but [this website](https://topforeignstocks.com/downloads/) contains Fortune 500 Global  excel data in a spreadsheet. However, they are sorted by revenue, market-cap is missing, and the last spreadsheet was from 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming market-cap weights are all that matters (but not the exact market cap values), the easiest (free) way is probably to get the data from ETF holdings. ACWI is the ETF tracking MSCI All Country World Index. Here's some sample code to get the top 500 holdings:

```
data = pd.read_csv("https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239600/ishares-msci-acwi-etf/1467271812596.ajax?fileType=csv&fileName=ACWI_holdings&dataType=fund", skiprows=9)
df = data[['Ticker', 'Name', 'Market Value', 'Weight (%)']].dropna().iloc[:500]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of tickers that you are interested in (which can be collected very easily), then you can use the TDAmeritrade API to collect this data. Although, non-US company data may be limited. Market cap is available for almost all companies from my experience, though.

Comment: Doesn't look like they provide data in non-US exchanges.

Answer (score 0):

From PDF to Excel, you may want to try AnyBizSoft's PDF Converter.

With Python and InvestPY, you can retrieve stock info like Total Revenue, Gross Profit,  Operating Income, Net Income etc.

https://investpy.readthedocs.io/_api/stocks.html

Answer (score 0):

Try signing up for Alpaca Markets and using their API; they have a table with the entire universe of securities. The table also includes Market Cap; and its free. Other than that I believe using a Robinhood API and access one of their pre-built lists.

Answer (score 0):

Companies ranked by Market Cap gives you the desired list, I did not find a better solution:

https://companiesmarketcap.com/

You can download the data as CSV and open in Excel.
You have to move to the next 100, though, to get the 500.